# Is it possible to pivot a list without using SQL?

Tags: python, python-2.7

What's the best way to pivot a list of lists?

I have a list of lists:

```
+-------+--------+-----+
| file1 | parama | 112 |
| file1 | paramb |  54 |
| file1 | paramd | 234 |
| file2 | paramb |  63 |
| file2 | paramd | 334 |
| file2 | paramz |  11 |
| file3 | parama |  34 |
+-------+--------+-----+
```

Can we pivot this list to get the following result:

```
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
|        | File1 | File2 | File3 |
| parama | 112   | -     | 34    |
| paramb | 54    | 63    | -     |
| paramd | 234   | 334   | -     |
| paramz | -     | 11    | -     |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
```

**What's the best way to pivot a list of lists?**

Comment: Can you provide the actual list of lists as well?

Comment: Using pandas, just use `df.pivot(index=1, columns=0)`

Comment: @MattDMo is it possible to get it on windows?

Comment: What do you mean? I just ran it on Windows...

Comment: how would i get pandas on windows

Comment: Christoph Gohlke's [Python Extension Packages for Windows Repository](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) has a wide selection of self-extracting `.exe` installers for many Python modules related to numeric and scientific computing, among others. Just pick the installer for the version of Python you're running, and whether it's 32- or 64-bit, and you're all set.